Comparing folders depending on their name and copy specific file (VBA Code)
I want to continue the following code to check the folders inside the "destFolderPath", and extract the month and year from the folders names "mmmyy" and then compare folders names to find which folder name is latest for example if we have "Jul24" and "May24" the "Jul24" will be the latest and then open its folder and search for the excel file with name "FP Sizing - "Requestname" - Temp" or "FP Resizing - "Requestname" - Temp" and copy it inside the "destFolderPath" folder, I tried several approaches with no good:
Sub CopyAllFolders(folders As Collection, destFolderPath As String)
Dim fso As Object
Dim folderPath As Variant
Dim folderName As String
Dim monthFolderName As String
Dim yearFolderName As String
Dim typeFolderName As String
Dim newFolderPath As String

' Initialize FileSystemObject
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

' Ensure the destination folder exists
If Dir(destFolderPath, vbDirectory) = "" Then
    MkDir destFolderPath
End If

' Loop through each folder in the collection and copy it to the destination folder
For Each folderPath In folders
    ' Extract the folder name (process folder)
    folderName = fso.GetFolder(folderPath).Name

    ' Extract the month folder name (parent folder name of the current folder)
    monthFolderName = fso.GetFolder(fso.GetParentFolderName(folderPath)).Name
    
    ' Extract the year folder name (parent of the month folder)
    yearFolderName = fso.GetFolder(fso.GetParentFolderName(fso.GetParentFolderName(folderPath))).Name
    
    ' Extract the type folder name (parent of the year folder)
    typeFolderName = fso.GetFolder(fso.GetParentFolderName(fso.GetParentFolderName(fso.GetParentFolderName(folderPath)))).Name
    
    ' Convert monthFolderName from "mmm-yy" to "mmmyy" (e.g., "Sep-23" becomes "0923")
    monthFolderName = Format(DateValue("01-" & monthFolderName), "mmmyy")
    
    ' Create the new folder path as "typeFolderName mmyy"
    newFolderPath = destFolderPath & "\" & typeFolderName & "-" & monthFolderName
    
    ' Ensure the new folder exists
    If Dir(newFolderPath, vbDirectory) = "" Then
        MkDir newFolderPath
    End If

    ' Check if the folder exists before attempting to copy
    If fso.FolderExists(folderPath) Then
        On Error Resume Next ' Ignore errors during copy operation
        fso.CopyFolder source:=folderPath, destination:=newFolderPath, OverwriteFiles:=True
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            MsgBox "Error copying folder: " & folderPath & " to " & newFolderPath & vbCrLf & "Error: " & Err.Description
            Err.Clear
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0 ' Resume normal error handling
    Else
        MsgBox "Source folder does not exist: " & folderPath
    End If
Next folderPath

' Clean up
Set fso = Nothing
End Sub


It would be useful to see some sample data

folders is a collection of strings?  Your code doesn't seem to match your description of what you want to do...
